# Where is the proper place to put a user-related function in Laravel 5.0

Tags: php, laravel

**The relevant portion of my application is set up as follows:**

- A Users table, with unique user IDs
- A Teams table, with unique team IDs
- A Team_Membership table, with
  a unique ID and a column for a User ID    and a Team ID, to denote
  that a user belongs to a team.

A user can be on an unlimited number of teams.

I have a function to retrieve an array of the teams a given user belongs to. It would generally be called in the scope of the current logged in user to get their active teams, but will also be used in administrative functions to return the teams of a given user ID.

My first thought was to make the function callable from the user model, so for a given user object, I could do as follows

```
$teams = $user->get_teams();
```

or

```
$teams = User::get_teams($user_id);
```

But I'm not sure if this is generally considered best practice in Laravel for this type of functionality. Where should this function be located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you are talking about something that laravel already does for you if you are using Eloquent.

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'users';

    public function teams()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Team::class);
    }
}

class Team extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'teams';

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

In addition to the `users` and `teams` table you would make a pivot table:

```
team_user
    id - integer
    team_id - integer
    user_id - integer
```

and laravel does the rest.

```php
$userId = 1;

$user = User::with('teams')->find($userId);

$teams = $user->teams;
```

Comment: Beautiful! I'm very new to Laravel and full-featured ORMs like Eloquent in general, so this is a wonderful thing to find. For future reference though, if I had to make a custom function for something like this, would the User model be the correct place to put it?